# Как правильно использовать redux в отправке формы

Tags: reactjs, redux

Немножко не понятно, как в моем случае применять redux при отправке формы.
index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import  { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Auth from './component/AuthForm';
import Helmet from './aplication';

function user(state = {}, action){
    if(action.type === 'ADD_USER'){
        return [
            ...state,
            action.user
        ];
    }
    return state;
}

const store = createStore(user, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
            <Helmet title='Авторизация'/>
            <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Auth}/>
                        <Route path='/index' render={() => <div>Index</div>}/>
                    </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
        </div>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

И форма

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import RaiseButtin from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

injectTapEventPlugin();

export default class UserForm extends Component{
    state = {
        form: {
            login: "",
            password: ""
        },
        error: "",
        redirectTo: "",
    };

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
//По логике тут я должен его вынести, верно dispather? 
        axios.post('/api/user', this.state.form)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data === false){
                    this.setState({ error: 'Неверный логин или пароль'});
                } else {
                    this.setState({redirectTo: '/index'});
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;

        this.setState( prevState => ({
            form: {
                ...prevState.form,
                [name]: value,
            }
        }));
    };

    render(){
        const { form, error, redirectTo } = this.state;
        if(redirectTo) return <Redirect to={redirectTo}/>;
        return(
            <div className='authForm'>
                <h1>Авторизация</h1>
                <div className='error'>{error}</div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <MuiThemeProvider>
                        <TextField
                            hintText="Введите логин"
                            name="login"
                            fullWidth={true}
                            value={form.login}
                            required={true}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                    <MuiThemeProvider>
                        <TextField
                            hintText="Введите пароль"
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            fullWidth={true}
                            value={form.password}
                            required={true}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                    <MuiThemeProvider>
                        <RaiseButtin label="Войти" fullWidth={true} className="authForm-button"> <input type="submit" className="authForm-input" /> </RaiseButtin>
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: вы имеете в виде, что вы хотите сабмит формы организовать в виден редакс экшна?

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko да

Answer (score -1, accepted):

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import  { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import Helmet from './aplication';
import loginReducers from './reducer/loginDucks';
import Home from "./Home";
import Auth from "./AuthForm";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login: loginReducers,
});

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('auth'));

ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
        <Helmet title='Авторизация'/>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' component={Auth}/>
                    <Route path='/index' render={() => sessionStorage.getItem('auth') !== null ? (<Redirect to='/'/>) : (<Home />)}/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
        </div>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

loginDucks.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'LOGIN_REQUEST',
    LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
    LOGIN_ERROR = 'LOGIN_ERROR';

const loginSuccess = data => ({
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    payload: {id: data.id, login: data.login, name: data.name}
});

const loginError = data => ({
    type: LOGIN_ERROR,
    payload: data
});

export const login = form => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/api/user', form);

        if (!res.data || res.data === false) {
            dispatch(loginError('Неправильный логин или пароль'));
        } else {
            dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
        }
    } catch (e) {
        dispatch(loginError(e.response.data));
    }
};

const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
    shouldRedirect: false,
    errorMessage: '',
    user: false,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type){
        case LOGIN_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
                isError: false
            };
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            sessionStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(payload));
            return {
                ...state,
                user: payload,
                isLoading: false,
                shouldRedirect: true
            };
        case LOGIN_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                errorMessage: payload,
                isLoading: false,
                isError: true,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

AuthForm

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { connect }from 'react-redux';
import { login } from './reducer/loginDucks';

class UserForm extends Component{
      ...
    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.login(this.state.form);
    };

    ...
    render(){
        const { form } = this.state;
        const { isLoading, isError, shouldRedirect, errorMessage } = this.props;
        if (shouldRedirect) return <Redirect to='/index'/>;
        return(
            ...
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isLoading: state.login.isLoading,
    isError: state.login.isError,
    shouldRedirect: state.login.shouldRedirect,
    errorMessage: state.login.errorMessage,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    login,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserForm)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```